# Updating partial entity using Entity Framework (with razor view)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an entity:

```
public class Organization
{
    public int OrganizationId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(160)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Team> Teams { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

I have created a `OrganizationViewModel` for representing data to view as well as creating new entities. I later map it using Automapper before saving changes to database using Entity Framework...

```
public class OrganizationViewModel
{
    public int OrganizationId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(160)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ApplicationUser> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

I have created an action method Edit which should only allow user to edit property Name (for this example only, but in reality, it does update many other properties which I have slimmed down for this question)..

The Edit view only has two properties `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.OrganizationId)` and `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)`

Now in `[HttpPost]`

I got `OrganizationViewModel` with updated `Name` property but property `Persons` remains null, if there are users already present in an organization EF throws an error as it is not expected by the context.

I could have updated the properties I want to update EXPLICITLY in Post method but I don't want to do everything manually. Is there any other way where I can say that just update the entities I want. I tried using `Bind`'s `Include` and `Exclude` but it has `null` for Persons as well.

Help me :)

Comment: The `Bind` attribute is for binding data sent from the view to the controller. Are you wanting `Persons` to be populated (are you editing them?) in which case have you generated form controls for each property of `ApplicationUser`, and if so how?

Comment: yes.. I want Persons to be populated but I don't want to show them in `Edit.cshtml`

Comment: But why? If you don't include form controls for each property of `ApplicationUser` then no data will be sent from the client to the POST method. If you not editing them, then you would not do that anyway. If you need the collection of `ApplicationUser` (not clear why you need that), then just get them again in the POST method.

Comment: I agree with you. However, automapper is causing an issue. I only update certain properties in Edit view. I post the data back to POST method and remap it with `Organization'. However, since I am using `OrganizationViewModel`, `Automapper` overrides existing values of Persons with `null` from the view model which I want to avoid. I am not sure if you got my question.

Comment: Automapper is primarily for mapping data models to view models. In a POST method, you would get the data model from the database and update its properties based on the view model - in your case something like `Organization dataModel = db.Organizations.Where(x => OrganizationId == viewModel.OrganizationId).FirstOrDefault(); dataModel.Name = viewModel.Name; db.SaveChanges();`

Comment: So you mean to say, I should be manually updating the properties? I would have done that but won't it produce code redundancy? @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 0):

If you create a view model that contains only the OrganizationId and Name properties that are edited by this view, you can achieve it by executing

```
db.Entry(db.Organizations
  .First(x => OrganizationId == viewModel.OrganizationId))
  .CurrentValues.SetValues(yourViewModel);
```

yourViewModel - can be any object with set of properties that you want to update, so you don't need to repeat your code but you have to have a specific view model for each operation. You may have it even locally for the update method and automap to it but it must have only properties you want to update.